# Modify post image in full size

Tags: php, wp-query, functions, wpdb

I have a website where the client attached many “full size” images to posts, most of them in 5000px width, is it possible to run something for resizing those images to large? Instead of going through each post and update them to large. Any ideas?

Comment: There are hundrets if not thousands of plugins which can do that. Imsanity, Image Optimizer, Smush Image Compression just to name three.

Comment: What I'm actually after is to take any images that were inserted into a posts as Full size (in Display Settings) and instead make them the Large size.